# do not update if exists postgres

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have table that has unique constraint on (uid,client_fact). when I try to update 
client_fact it raise an error on constraint which is obvious because if I say update client_fact to value 2 where user_id is 1 and if there is already a combination of these two column it raise an exception. but is there any way where I can skip that and continue updating others.

The Query I am using is

```
UPDATE  user_ft
SET client_fact_id = 779,
WHERE client_fact_id in (select client_fact_id 
                         from user_ft 
                         where client_fact_id = 778 
                           and updated_date::date =< '2015-05-28') 
 and not exists (select uid ,client_fact_id 
                 from user_ft 
                 where  client_fact_id = 779)
```

I used the not exists clause to handle the case were I have combination of user and factid already sitting in table. It ran successfully but didn't updated anything.

Comment: Please edit your question and show the query you are using.

Comment: Also please specify the postgresql version you're using, as the available options differ between versions.

Comment: It sounds like you want `UPDATE ... WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT ...)` or an `UPDATE ... FROM ...` but it's hard to tell from the total lack of information provided here.

Comment: I have edited my question and added the query I am using.

Answer (score 0):

Got it ...
we don't need to use not exists. .. as this will result skipping all rows I canged my query to have a look if user in table with this combination then don't consider that user in query. see below corrected query

```
 UPDATE  user_ft SET client_fact_id = 779
 WHERE client_fact_id in (select client_fact_id from user_ft 
                           where client_fact_id = 778  and 
                           updated_date::date =< '2015-05-28') 
 and uid not in (select uid  
                 from user_ft 
                  where  client_fact_id = 779)
```

Thanks everyone